# Ember: difference between unloadRecord and destroy for new records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the context of a route model that hasn't been persisted to the backend yet (its id is `null` still and we haven't called `save` yet), if we want to discard the record, is it more correct to use `unloadRecord` or `destroy`?

Context: For use when a form is transitioned away from but is neither saved nor canceled. I'm new to ember and I am a bit confused by the fact that `unloadRecord` is private for Model but not for Store. It may be obvious but I am also not positive when it is correct to refer to the object as a model vs. a record (I am assuming they are sometimes used interchangeably but it's technically correct to call them records if they are existing instances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of situation [rollbackAttributes](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollbackAttributes) method exists. If model is not persisted yet, it will be removed from store. Also, don't create model before user clicks save, but:

1. Bind form to controller's properties. (I usually use POJO which contains all model's fields)
2. When user clicks save button, validate data, create model and call save method
3. If persisting model to your backend fails, rollbackAttributes. If persisting is successfull, clear controller properties (so when user will add next entity, form will be clean) and redirect away.

Store's [unloadRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_unloadRecord) unloads **persisted** record from store (so you will not have it locally, but may have or not have it on backend).

Comment: In your opinion, why is `rollbackAttributes` is more correct than `destroyRecord`?

Comment: @maffews purpose of ``destroyRecord`` is deleting **persisted** record both from store and backend, while question is about new record, not persisted yet. That's why using it is less correct. You have no guaranty that it will work correctly with not persisted records in future versions.

Comment: Is this supported at all in the documentation or code comments? I've searched in both and I can't find anything that says `destroyRecord` is only for persisted records. Based on the way `destroyRecord`'s handling of unsaved records was previously treated as an [bug](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1593), I think that both `destroyRecord` and `deleteRecord` are appropriate, if not more so than than `rollbackAttributes`.

Comment: @Marks From [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_destroyRecord) on deleteRecord: "**Marks the record as deleted** but does not save it. You must call save afterwards if you want to persist it. You might use this method if you want to allow the user to still rollbackAttributes() after a delete it was made." Something, that not persisted, can not be deleted. And code exapmle there is about deleting existing record. Also, nothing is said about new records, but said that you should call save method.

Comment: Even when you call `rollbackAttributes` you are deleting the record because calling `rollbackAttributes` on a new model puts the record into the `root.deleted.saved`/`isDeleted` state. Because the internal and external state of a new model that gets rolled back is deleted, I think it's safe to say that you can delete any model whether or not it is persisted.

Comment: @maffews I don't have enough time for this holy war. You are free to write your code as you wish. In my opinion, using deleteRecord / destroyRecord is incorrect. Docs are very clear about rollbackAttributes, while destroyRecord are just happened to work.

Comment: If you take a look at how calling `rollbackAttributes` causes a new record to enter the deleted state, you can see that [calling `rollbackAttributes` is just an indirect way to delete](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/32d5e5791a909273ed8eeb48c32828d544aa6b5e/addon/-private/system/model/states.js#L406) [edit: Sorry, I posted this before refreshing and seeing your comment. This isn't a holy war, I'm just trying to get to the truth so we can avoid spreading incorrect information]

Comment: @maffews rollbackAttributes rollbacks your changes. ``deleteRecord`` deletes a record. Period. Yes, they fixed RESTAdapter for people, who wanted to delete not persisted record with ``destroyRecord``. But that doesn't mean calling ``destroyRecord`` became a more correct way than calling ``rollbackAttributes``. BTW that's the last answer from me in this thread, its pissing me off already. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5):

If you create but don't save a record it will be in the `root.loaded.created.uncommitted` state (Ember 2.4). Calling `destroyRecord` will schedule a `save` but will also immediately change the state to `root.deleted.saved`, so the `save` request will never be executed.

You can verify this in your browser by checking the network requests created by calling `destroyRecord` on an newly created record.

There is some additional work performed around scheduling a `save` when calling `destroyRecord` as opposed to `unloadRecord`, so the trade-off here is between scheduling a save that is never executed and the additional complexity of determining the model state prior to deleting the record.

`unloadRecord` - unloads record from the store

`deleteRecord` - delete the record but do not save it (must call `save`)

`destroyRecord` - calls `deleteRecord` and `save`

`rollbackAttributes` - rolls back attributes or, if model `isNew`, removes it from the store

Answer (score 3):

`unloadRecord` - is the right option.

Model - `destroyRecord` -> will call adapter deleteRecord which means it will raise delete request to server for particular record.

Store - `unloadRecord` -> It will only unload from store and it will not raise any request to server. you can only unload non dirty records

Model - `unloadRecord` -> it's not at all required. since if record is created then you will have entry in store, so you can always go through store's `unloadRecord` method to remove non dirty records.

Comment: Calling `destroyRecord` on a newly created record does result in a call to `save`, but Ember handles this intelligently and will not actually execute a remote request to persist the change to the server.